# Get BitmapImage Properties after scaled and tweened -CreateJS

Tags: javascript, properties, bitmap, drawing, easeljs

I add to the stage 5 playcard that I modify with a setTransform and  tween function.
After they are on the stage I want to give them a border when they get clicked.
The creation of the border is in the click event handler.
My problem is that I can not get exact widht, height x and y coordinates of the cards I clicked.

Here is my code:

```
card3.setTransform(((i * card.getWidth() + 600) ) + (10 * i),card.getHeight(),0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
selbst.skew_cards_verso(i);
this._stage.addChild(card3);
createjs.Tween.get(card3).wait(1500).to({scaleX:skillpokerjs.Card.SCALE, scaleY:skillpokerjs.Card.SCALE,alpha:1, skewY:0,regY:card3.image.height/2}, 1500, createjs.Ease.linear);
```

Here is the click event handler:

```
p.verso_card_click = function(evt,card)
{

    var g = new createjs.Graphics();
    var color = createjs.Graphics.getRGB(255,0,0);
    var shape = new createjs.Shape(g);
    g.setStrokeStyle(1);
    g.beginStroke(color);
    g.moveTo(card.data.x,(card.data.y /.6));
    g.lineTo((card.data.image.width /.6),card.data.y);
    g.lineTo(evt.target.image.width,evt.target.image.height);
    g.lineTo(evt.target.x,evt.target.image.height);
    g.lineTo(evt.target.x,evt.target.y);
    this._stage.addChild(shape);



};
```

In the event handler the parameter card is the card I click on. It is the same with event.target.

The card are on the stage in a row side by side.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you checked out the `bmp.getBounds()` method? It should give you transformed coordinates.

Comment: @Lanny thank you for the advice but unfortunately I get the values for the cards before the transformation